# Brownie: TransactionReceipt from a reverted tx inside a script

Tags: brownie, revert-opcode

In the Brownie-documentation it says:

> Debugging Tools
> When using the console, transactions that revert still return a TransactionReceipt object. This object provides access to various attributes and methods that help you determine why it reverted.

Is there a way to get to the TransactionReceipt from a reverted tx inside a script? (not at the Brownie-console)?

Answer (score 1):

If you need your test to read the `tx`, then no.

If you want to debug an unexpected revert:
When executing the tests, use `brownie test --interactive`.  This will drop you into a Brownie console upon test failure.  From there, use `chain.undo` to roll back the most recent transaction.  Copy/paste the failed transaction prefixed with `tx =`  and you can interact with the transaction receipt as desired.